# drop down list that include an extra text

Tags: javascript

I want to make a drop down list. should I control the red text from javascript? [image: The red color text]

Comment: It depends, do you want to detect the preferred language and add the extra text on the detected language to the drop down list? If so, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want static text, it can be done using css as displayed in code below, otherwise you can change the text of **extraText** class using javascript.

Preview

[image]

[Working JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/917thaae/)

HTML

```
<div class="selectContainer">
    <select>
      <option>English</option>
      <option>Hindi</option>
      <option>Gujarati</option>
    </select>
   <div class="extraText">Preferred Language</div>
</div>
```

css

```
       .selectContainer{
            width:200px;
            margin: 10px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .selectContainer select{
            width: 100%;
        }
        .extraText{
            position: absolute;
            right: 20px;
            top:2px;
            color:#db4040;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: smaller;
        }
```